# UEFI Ubuntu Install (Dell XPS P31F)

Tags: ubuntu, uefi

Ubuntu doesn't boot on my machine, I wiped Windows off alltogether, just want Ubuntu only running on it.

The laptop has also a 32Gb SSD drive for quick booting Windows, which I don't mind not using if it makes the install easier, but the other HDD is a 500Gb which I don't need to recover any files from it.

The Boot Repair tool didn't work, and this is its output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YzDJP5SQpz/

My BIOS setup looks like this:

[image: BIOS UEFI setup]

The issue manifests by not getting anything at the boot stage, only a cursor can be seen, and no other output is displayed.

Comment: Ever since I have a laptop with UEFI (it's even got WIFI), I've been using rEFind, perhaps have a look: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: You seem to be saying that there’s nothing on the system that you need to save.  Can you just reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boot Repair Tool says your `/dev/sda` (= the disk the installed Ubuntu is supposed to boot from) has `Disklabel type: dos` and `Boot files: /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img`, so the installation expected to do a legacy MBR-style boot, and installed a version of GRUB tailored for it.

On the other hand, your setup screen clearly indicates your system is set to boot in the UEFI style.

Your system should have not one, but *two* options for booting an installer from any given CD-ROM or USB installation media. One should result in a native UEFI-style boot; the other, which you apparently have used, is legacy MBR-style boot.

The trick is, *you must boot the OS installer using the same style the installed OS is expected to use.*

If you boot the installer in MBR style, it won't be able to access EFI boot variables in the system NVRAM, and so won't be able to complete the installation of an UEFI-style bootloader. It will also assume that a MBR-style partitioning and bootloader is what you need: it will create a MBR-style partition table if re-partitioning disks from scratch, and will not create the EFI system partition (ESP).

If there is nothing you need to keep on the system, you should boot the Ubuntu installer again, but in UEFI style this time. Then you should remove all existing partitions, so that the installer can flip the partitioning style to GPT.

Comment: Many thanks, I switched to legacy boot, and now I have the booting problem sorted.

Comment: you might be interested in http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html to actually understand what goes on... helped me a lot while implementing UEFI support in ALT Linux back then

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the link. I wish there was a tl;dr, happy with the current legacy non-UEFI solution.